# nodejs - how to compare two hashes password of bcrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, passwords, bcrypt

Hello I need some help with this issue after I search the solution and I have not found yet,

I want to compare 2 hash password with bcrypt of the same password, 
how do I do it?

for example:

I have these 2 hash password that came from the same password in bcrypt:

```
var password = E@Js#07Do=U$
var hash1 = $2a$10$fKAyjaG0pCkisZfRpKsBxursD6QigXQpm1TaPBDZ4KhIZRguYPKHe
var hash2 = $2a$10$mgApOcRIp7RSK3lRIIlQ5e/GjVFbxAFytGAEc0Bo17..r8v2pPR22
// that's not working for me
bcrypt.compare(passwordHash, userPasswordLoginHash, function(err, isMatch) {
   if (err) throw err;
   if(isMatch){
      console.log('correct password!')
   }
   callback(null, isMatch);
});
```

how can i compare them, to determine that they came from the same password, by using bcryptjs npm package?

Comment: i think you can only compare a plain text password to a hashed one

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is impossible by design - as a core security property of true password hashing.

If you could compare two password hashes *without knowing the original password*, then if an attacker cracked one password on the system, they would *instantly* know the passwords of *all* users who are using that password, without any additional work. It should be immediately obvious why this would be a bad thing.

For example, if passwords were stored using a hash inappropriate for password storage (such as MD5), then if 50 users had a password of 'password', then all of their hashed passwords would have the identical MD5 hash ('5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99'), and cracking one of them would reveal the password of *all 50 users*.

You can't do that with a modern password hash like bcrypt. The only way to "compare" two modern password hashes is *to know the plaintext in advance*, and then apply the algorithm using the salt in each hash. And even if two users have the same password, the attacker has to perform the same expensive computation to crack each of them independently, because the unique salts make each hash unique.

More generally - and this may sound a bit bold - but there is no legitimate use case for any system or administrator to *ever* compare two *different* users' passwords. User passwords should be 100% independent and 100% opaque to the system once stored. If a system or business case requires this kind of comparison, it should be redesigned to eliminate that requirement.

Comment: Actually there are use cases.
For example I am hashing user ids for anonymity, but in order to know that two posts were made by the same user on client side, I would want to compare their hashed ids...

Comment: Interesting. That's not password hashing, then. Is the purpose to prevent anyone from correlating that the same user posted each post? If so, you'd have to crack them both independently to make that correlation. But if your goal is to have quasi-anonymity but allow direct correlation that the same user posted the posts (as tripcodes are used elsewhere), then unless you force the hashes to have the same salt, you won't be able to directly compare the two hashes without knowing the username or cracking them. In other words, the method wouldn't match the use case - just as I suggested.

Comment: cf. tripcode anonymity use: http://tanasinn.info/wiki/A_Guide_to_Anonymous_Boards#Anonymity.2C_Names.2C_IDs_and_Tripcodes. You *could* use bcrypt for this ... but you'd have to hold the salt constant, so that the two hashes would be identical.

Comment: How about if a user changes their password, and you want to validate that they haven't reused any of their last, say, 24 passwords?  You would need to store the previous 24 password hashes, and compare the new password to each.  Ideally, you would not want to rehash the new password for each of the 24 checks.

Comment: That's *exactly* how password history verification is usually done. If there's one thing that's worse than not hashing someone's current password, it's not hashing their password *history*, allowing an attacker to study all previous passwords, and disclosing the psychology of *how* the user selects passwords.

Comment: So how on the earth is the stored hash "used" to know whether the user has input the correct password in future if there is not some comparing mechanism and also not saving the plaintext password?

Comment: Different kind of comparison. :) When the user supplies the plaintext, *you already have the plaintext* - so you can hash the plaintext, and then compare the results to the stored hash to see if they match. Comparing *two hashes for which the plaintext is not known* is a whole different beast. My answer should clarify why the alternative is an anti-feature.

Answer (score 5):

"With bcrypt lib you compare plain text password to the one hashed using the same lib."

The problem is with a micro services architecture, that is very insecure.  If I have a front end passing an unhashed password to the backend, the unhashed password is getting logged (possibly in multiple places) before it gets compared against the hash in the DB on the system backend.

Comment: Yea, it doesn't have to be a micro services architecture. Any architecture using bcrypt would essentially involve passing plaintext password over the wire ? (https helps but not a silver bullet)

Comment: that's not the fault of it being a microservice architecture but of the way it is implemented. It should never log those fields, period.

Comment: also agree in practice this actually inflicts unsecure cleartext password storage / transmission

Comment: Many logging libraries provide filters, so you've got to pass a logger instance around with the current password to be filtered out. You can even write a wrapper doing just that yourself easily. But of course, that does not really guarantee that this filter is applied everywhere properly. "It should never", as @jwenting says, is an unsufficient premise to begin with when it comes down to security issues.

Answer (score 4):

With `bcrypt` lib you compare plain text password to the one hashed using the same lib.

Say you hashed a password

```
const myPlaintextPassword = 'E@Js#07Do=U$'
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds, function(err, hash) {
  // Store hash in your password DB.
  // example output, taking your hash
  // hash = $2a$10$fKAyjaG0pCkisZfRpKsBxursD6QigXQpm1TaPBDZ4KhIZRguYPKHe
});
```

You compare like:

```
// db query, get hashed password, found hash
// hash = $2a$10$fKAyjaG0pCkisZfRpKsBxursD6QigXQpm1TaPBDZ4KhIZRguYPKHe
// User input again:
const myPlaintextPassword = 'E@Js#07Do=U$'
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, function(err, res) {
  // res is true as the original password is the same
  // res == true
});
```

Comment: I believe that the question isn't about how to verify a password, but how to *compare two hashes* to see if they are the same password.

Comment: you've already answered that part :). Adding how to compare, in case OP is confused going about implementing password verification

Answer (score 0):

For a bit extra security you can encrypt the password in the front-end and decrypt and compare in the back-end

Comment: Front end code is publicly available to the client meaning that you can reverse engineer the request meaning that this provides no extra security, just a waste of time.

Comment: In any other case he can use ssl