# How to NOT send a plain-text password to BE and still verify it

Tags: node.js, vue.js, security, authentication, bcrypt

I am having a dillema now ..

I am building an application on VueJS and NodeJS .. and during the authentication, I need to verify whether the password and username match (obviously).

The problem is, I don't want to send the plaintext password from FE (VueJS) to the BE (NodeJS) but already encrypted with bcrypt

The problem is, there is no way for me to check if the given hash matches the stored one in the database. so this leaves me with sending the plain text password - but from my paranoid security perspective, it's not ok ...

How do you guys solve this?

Comment: but bcrypt with a salt will never generates the same hashes :)  see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801772/nodejs-how-to-compare-two-hashes-password-of-bcrypt

Comment: Yes, it won't. The question doesn't make it clear whether you're already using bcrypt or just intend to. In the first case it's not possible to send a hash, unless you want to expose original salt to a client, which defies the purpose of using bcrypt to some extent. You could use asymmetric encryption for transmitted password. Public key can be stolen but this may still help if your primary concern is that plain password can be *easily* sniffed from HTTPS traffic.

Comment: How many users are you dealing with? Your process *could* be: 1) collect user identifier. 2) Send to back end. 3) collect hashed passwords from back end 4) send these to front end 5) compare at the front end JS 6) send agknowledgement back to the backed as to which password hash matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is standard practice to send "plaintext" passwords over HTTPS. The passwords are ultimately not plaintext, since the client-server communication is encrypted as per TLS.

Encrypting the password before sending it in HTTPS doesn't accomplish much: if the attacker got their hands on the encrypted password they could simply use it as if it were the actual password, the server wouldn't know the difference. The only advantage it would provide is protecting users that use the same password for multiple sites, but it wouldn't make your site any safer.

Comment: hmm makes sense.. fair point ... thank you .. I will send it plain then

Answer (score 0):

As indicated, generally the security layer of HTTPS is trusted.

Technically speaking, it is possible to split the password hashing in two. You can simply perform one number of iterations on the client (browser) and the remaining on the server. You want to perform at least one iteration on the server as you would otherwise get the value that the clients send to be stored in the database: i.e. getting a copy of the values in the database would directly leak all login credentials... not good.

So this would likely mean two separate bcrypt hashes to be performed if you want to keep using that algorithm. You can reuse the same salt I suppose, but storing a separate one should always be preferred. Of course, performing bcrypt at the client side will spike the CPU locally, which may hamper performance, spin up fans etc., and that's assuming the JS will run OK.

Finally, if the TLS is completely broken then somebody can simply inject a script that will leak the password. So hashing it locally will only increase security by a relatively small margin. It could still be somewhat useful against future decryption attempts, but in the end you'll have to rely on TLS anyways. So the answer to "How do you guys solve this?" is generally: we don't. It might make slightly more sense in a mobile app or full size application.

Interesting to know, there have been submissions such as Catena and Makwa to the password hashing competition that explicitly allow the client to perform part of the hashing. Generally this is more performed for *offloading* the password hashing to other systems and alleviate the use of valuable server resources.